# Will there be any special event in Paris on November 9th?

Tags: hotels, paris

I'm finding a hotel in Paris on November 9th at a reasonable price. (around 100 euros)

However, there is no room especially on that day. Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: You might want to change to an other hotel search site, the one I usually use does have a wide selection of rooms available, from about €40 up.

Comment: How about using AirBnB? It doesn't cost even €100.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localised.  One could ask the same for any day or any city.